# Using Room-Guava in Android, cannot find ListenableFuture

Tags: android-room, guava

I'm following this:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries

I'm trying to use **ListenableFuture** from Guava, so I included **androidx.room:room-guava** but Android Studio keeps complaining that "*Cannot resolve symbol 'ListenableFuture'*" and doesn't suggest any relevant `import`.

What is the correct `import` to include in Java source?

Here is my code:

---

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
...
// Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:2.4.3"
```

---

**Java DAO interface**

```
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;

@Dao
public interface PressureMeasureDao
{
    @Insert
    public ListenableFuture<Integer> insertPressureMeasure(PressureMeasure pressureMeasure);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.room/room-guava/2.4.3 androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures is a runtime dependency. Please check if https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.concurrent/concurrent-futures is present. `ListenableFuture` comes from its transitive dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of the accepted answer. Moving to room 2.4.3 give me the same error, here is a working configuration with comments for dependencies. Hope that will help.

```
def room_version = "2.4.3" 
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
// listenablefuture add-on
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-android" --> optional
// To use CallbackToFutureAdapter
implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"
```

Source : https://developer.android.com/guide/background/listenablefuture